# Binomial Coefficients for $(x+1)^4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find $(x + 1)^4$ using binomial coefficients.

I'm confused as to how to start this, as I thought binomial coefficients were things like $9 \choose 2$.

Comment: start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficients

Comment: Intuitively, you have $(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)$  to get the term proportional to $x^2$ you need to choose two of the items to give you $1$ and two of them to give you $x$.  You can do this in ${4 \choose 2}$ ways.

Comment: You need $\dbinom 40$, $\dbinom 41$, $\dbinom 42$, $\dbinom 43$ and $\dbinom44$.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)?

$$(a+b)^n = \binom n0 a^nb^0 + \binom n1 a^{n-1}b^1 + \binom n2 a^{n-2}b^2 +\cdots + \binom nn a^0b^n $$

Comment: Oh! I remember this now. So $(x+1)^4 = (4/0)x^4 1^0 + (4/1)x^3 1^1 + (4/2)x^2 1^2 + (4/3)x^1 1^3 + (4/4)x^0 1^4$

Comment: Use the command  \dbinom{a}{b} to get $\dbinom{a}{b}$

Comment: and for small binomial coefficients you can use the Pascal's triangle to calculate them (if you don't like using formulat :D)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle

Comment: @Meowmix That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\binom nr=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$$

So, $\binom 92=\frac{9(9-1)}{2!}=\frac{9\cdot8}{2\cdot1}=36$

$$(x+1)^4=\sum_{0\le r\le 4}\binom  4r(1)^{4-r}x^r$$

Comment: I know this is how you compute binomial coefficients, I am just confused as to what $n$ and $r$ are in this situation.

Comment: @Meowmix, here $n=4$ and integer $r$ varies from $0$ to $n=4$

Answer (score 0):

Use this: $(x+y)^n=$ $n \choose 0 $ $x^n y^0$+$n \choose 1 $ $x^{n-1}y^1$+$n \choose 2 $ $x^{n-2}y^2$+ $\dots$ +$n \choose n $ $x^0y^n$

What's the $r^{th}$ term's coefficients using this?

Answer (score 0):

Use  $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n T_r$$
$$T_r= \ ^nC_r\times  x^{r}y^{n-r}$$

so for $(1+x)^n $you come with $$T_r= \ ^nC_r x^r$$

$$^nC_r=\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$$

Comment: Here $^nC_r$ is $\binom nr$ Whatever you say.